# C# Delegates and Global Scoping

Tags: c#, delegates, global

I am new to C# delegates and I'm trying to make a simple class that works with them. I want instances of the class to be able to take a function as an argument, store it within a delegate, and then call that delegate when prompted by an external source. Something like:

```
class UsesDelegates {

    private delegate void my_delegate_type();
    private my_delegate_type del;

    public void GetDelegate ( /*Not sure what goes here*/ ) {...}
    public void CallDelegate () {
         del();
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that since `my_delegate_type` is internal to the class, there is no way to construct it outside the class in order to pass it to `GetDelegate()`. I was hoping I would be able to pass the function name, perhaps as a string, to `GetDelegate()` so that the delegate could be constructed within the method, but I cannot find a way to do that. I realize that I am able to make `my_delegate_type` global and construct the delegate outside of this class, but it seems improper to make the type global because it is only being used by `UsesDelegates`. Is there a way to keep the type encapsulated while still achieving the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `delegate`, like so.

```
public class UsesDelegates
{
    private Action action;

    public void GetDelegate(Action action) => this.action = action;
    public void CallDelegate() => del();
}
```

You can then use it, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UsesDelegates usesDelegates = new UsesDelegates();
        usesDelegates.GetDelegate(Console.WriteLine);
        usesDelegates.CallDelegate();
    }
}
```

And `Action` supports parameters, by passing the types, like this: `Action<p1, p2>`, and if you need a return type, you can use `Func<return, p1, p2>`.